# MySQL: creating a user that can connect from multiple hosts

Tags: networking, permissions, mysql, database, database-administration

I'm using MySQL and I need to create an account that can connect from either the localhost or from another server, i.e. 10.1.1.1.  So I am doing:

```
CREATE USER 'bob'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
CREATE USER 'bob'@'10.1.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on MyDatabse.* to 'bob'@'localhost', 'bob'@'10.1.1.1';
```

This works fine, but is there any more elegant way to create a user account that is linked to multiple IPs or does it need to be done this way?

My main worry is that in the future, permissions will be updated form 'bob' account and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to restrict to host and do not want to specify based on a subnet or wildcard using `%`, that's the only way to do it. More details are available in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html).

I am still trying to find ways to eliminate overhead when managing authentication to large MySQL installations and have yet to find a perfect solution.